# UINavigationBar hidden property problem

Tags: ios, three20, uinavigationbar

Good day guys,

I was wondering if you could help me with my problem. I have a few views which are monitored by a TTNavigator. I've set the Navigation bar in my first view to be hidden the rest of the duration of the application. At first it all seemed well, i proceeded to the next view, then tried to navigate back to the first view, to my surprise the navigation bar's hidden property was set to "visible"...

The method I used was "`self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES/NO;`"

Comment: Where are you calling that method?

Comment: @Ben Wyatt: It is inside my viewDidLoad method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah, you're right. I think it's a bug in three20 framework. To workaround it, try:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0;
}
```

or:

```
[super showBars:NO animated:NO];
```

but it's a private three20 function, so it would give you a compile notice.

Comment: still nothing, well it was worth the try. Probably this is a bug of the TTFramework.

Comment: I'm using these 2 workrounds in my apps and it's working. Are you using the standard TTNavigator to push controllers?

Comment: yup, along with the URL mapping and calling used by the TTFramework